# Object pool for Java wrappers and String

Tags: java

As you all very well know sometimes Java uses object pools for wrappers and String types, sometimes it doesn't.

For example:

```
Integer i1 = 1;
Integer i2 = 1;
Integer i3 = new Integer(1);
String s1 = "String";
String s2 = "String";
String s3 = new String ("String");
System.out.println("(i1 == i2) " + (i1 == i2));
System.out.println("(i2 == i3) " + (i2 == i3));
System.out.println("(s1 == s2) " + (s1 == s2));
System.out.println("(s2 == s3) " + (s2 == s3));

Execution result:

(i1 == i2) true
(i2 == i3) false
(s1 == s2) true
(s2 == s3) false
```

As you see boxing of primitives takes objects from the pool, creating of a Strings via string literal takes objects from the pool, too. Such objects are actually the same object (**operator ==** returns true on them).

Other mechanisms of creating wrappers and Strings don't take objects from the pool. Objects created these ways are actually different objects (operator **== returns** false on them).

What confuses me is the fact that the pool is used partially.

If its a memory issue, why not use the pool all of the times?
If its not a memory issue - why use it at all?

The question is - what are the reasons for implementing such behavior (= partial usage of the pool)?

The question is rather theoretical, but it has practical application - it can help understand how correctly use custom objects pools and of course understanding how Java works is always good.

Comment: So it's the result of some trade off (how unexpected!!!). It's difficult to select the best answer. There's a couple of good candidates. So, I select the one that gives the "Java language specification" quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a speed concern, allocating a new `Integer` every single time would be both time and memory expensive. But by the same token allocating at start up too much at start up uses tons of memory and time.

Sadly it leads to some counter-intuitive behavior as you've found.

The result is this weird compromise that we have. The reasons for this behavior are discussed in the Java standard. (5.7)

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127, then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.
>   Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using existing implementation techniques. The rules above are a pragmatic compromise. The final clause above requires that certain common values always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. The implementation may cache these, lazily or eagerly.
>
> For other values, this formulation disallows any assumptions about the identity of the boxed values on the programmer's part. This would allow (but not require) sharing of some or all of these references.
>
> This ensures that in most common cases, the behavior will be the desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might, for example, cache all characters and shorts, as well as integers and longs in the range of -32K - +32K.

**tl;dr**

It's impossible to make it work perfectly, and it's too weird to not have it work at all. So we have it work for "most" of the time.

Answer (score 5):

> If its a memory issue, why not use the pool all of the times?

Pooling everything all the time is more expensive than a simple cache that sometimes fails: You need more sophisticated data structures (pooling small integers can be done with a simple and small array) and algorithms, and you must always go though that check even when the pool wouldn't help you. Moreover, you'd pool many objects that are never needed again, which is a waste of memory: You need more (useless) cache entries, and you need to manage that cache (or suffer from keeping useless objects alive).

> If its not a memory issue - why use it at all?

It *is* a memory issue. Lots of memory is saved by this optimization. Pooling *every* object doesn't necessarily reduce memory use, because not every object is used a lot. It's a trade off. The approach that was taken saves a significant amount of memory for some common use cases, without slowing down other operations unduly or wasting a lot of memory.

Answer (score 3):

There are various considerations. For example memory usage, but also language semantics.

```
 new Integer(1);
```

is an explicit object creation. Replacing this with a "get from pool" operator would change the language semantics.

```
 Integer.valueOf(1)
```

is the explicit "take from pool, if in pool range". Note that the pool is static, and implemented in Java, not in the virtual machine. You can look it up: `java.lang.Integer$IntegerCache`. I figure the Java specifications say that a cast from `int` to `Integer` are made by inserting a `Integer.valueOf` call.

Now if you look up how this cache is implemented, you will notice that there is a user tunable parameter for the cache size. By default, this cache just consists of an array `Integer[256]` keeping pre-initialized copies for `-128..127` (i.e. the value range of a byte). Apparently, this value range offers the best performance/memory tradeoff for common uses.

See e.g. http://martykopka.blogspot.de/2010/07/all-about-java-integer-cache.html for more details.

If you spend some time working on numerical computations in Java, you *do* feel a negative impact of autoboxing. For high performance numerics, the first rule of thumb is to avoid any kind of autoboxing. GNU Trove for example offers hashmaps and similar structures for primitive types, and the runtime and memory benefits are immense.

An `Integer` object occupies 16 bytes of memory - 4 times as much as an `int`. So above cache occupies around 5kb of memory, for example. This is something most applications can affort to waste. But obviously, you can't do this for all integers!

As for strings, the compiler needs to store them appropriately in the class file. So how do you store a string in a class file? The simplest way is to rewrite the code to something like this:

```
private static final char[] chars_12345 = new char[]{ 't', 'e', 's', 't'};

private static final String CONST_STRING_12345 = new String(chars_12345);
```

which does not rely on any magic handling of the `String` type. It's just a wrapped array of primitives. And of course, you want to store each unique string only once per class to reduce class size and thus load time.

Comment: Thanks, but your rather answer the question HOW it is done, not WHY.

Comment: Well, if you look at how it is done, there are also comments on why it is implemented this way, and not another. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a case of memory and speed.  You don't really want to create 4 billion Integer objects when the JVM starts up because most of the time they'll never be used.

For Strings, there's also the problem of finding matching strings in the interned pool.

String literals in source code are easy as the compiler can find and arrange to intern them, but if I create a string dynamically at runtime the JVM would have to go through the pool and search every string to see if it matched and could be reused and strings can

While there are data structures that could help speed that up, it's generally just simpler and faster to create a new object.

Comment: Finding matching object (in the pool) should be a problem (= will take some time and effort) not only for Strings, but for other objects, too.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer Generally, yes. But which objects are you thinking of specifically? For integers in a fixed range, an array works just fine.

Comment: I agree, finding an integer should be easier from low level perspective than an array of chars.

Answer (score 1):

See, the following segment of code:

```
Integer i1=1;
Integer i2=2;
String s1="String";
String s2="String";
```

The `i1`, `i2` are references only not objects, they booth are assigned the object `1`.
The same way `s1`, `s2` are references only not objects, they booth are assigned the object `"String"`.

Whereas at the following code:

```
Integer i3=new Integer(1);
String s3=new String("String");
```

The `new` operator creates a `new` `Object`.
Hope I cleared you.