# Do we have pools for all primitive types in PermGen area of Heap?

Tags: java, heap-memory, permgen

I know the concept of String pool in PermGen area of heap. So when we do something like

```
String firstString = "Stack";
String secondString = "Stack";
```

both references `firstString` and `secondString` point to the same object in the pool. But I tried the same for a variable of type **int**.

```
    int firstInt = 5;
    int secondInt = 5;

    if(firstInt == secondInt) {
        System.out.println("Both point to same allocated memory");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Both point to different allocated memory");
    }
```

and the result is `Both point to same object` and when i tried

```
Integer firstInteger = new Integer(2);
Integer secondInteger = new Integer(2);

    if(firstInteger == secondInteger) {
        System.out.println("Both point to same object");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Both point to different object");
    }
```

output is `Both point to different object`

I tried the same for **char** and the result is similar. So my question do we have pools for all primitive types like `int`, `char`? And when we actually create objects with same content using `new ()` as in the second case mentioned above is the object cloned and stored in same pool area or is it outside the pool?

Comment: In your first example with `int`, you are not dealing with objects at all but with **primitives**, so it does not apply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is so much misconception in your post, it is hard even to start explaining. Get some decent book. For now, some facts that might help you:

- String is not a primitive type,
- there are no pools of primitive types, because there cannot be a reference to a primitive type (the answer saying that they are only kept on the stack is plain wrong!)
- if you use `new`, you bypass pools anyway; so executing `new String("ala")` will always create a new String object; you cannot change the semantics of `new`;
- if you want to use available pools, use factory methods on objects (like `Integer.valueOf`), they will - to some extent - pool instances (it is not viable or beneficial to pool all possible values of `Integers`, `Floats` etc.).

Comment: +1, See also See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402794/object-pool-for-java-wrappers-and-string

Comment: and I did not mention anywhere that String is a primitive type!My question is that do we have similar pools for primitive types?

Comment: @AniketThakur - Why would you want pools of primitive types?

Comment: Take 1st case mentioned in my question. How does it print Both point to same object? My point to some where it must take care to ensure both firstInt and secondInt have the same memory allocated.

Comment: @AniketThakur - See my answer for that question - they have the same value, not the same memory.

Comment: @AniketThakur - please write this down on a piece of paper 100 times: "A primitive is not an object and does not have a reference." Then reread your question.

Comment: @parsifal I did not mean references i meant same memory allocation. Anyway I got the point.

Comment: On Oracle JVM, only Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Character do have their pools, so using "valueOf" is effective, but Float, Double do not.

Answer (score 1):

Primitives are not objects. They can be stored directly in the generated code.

In your second code block, you're testing equality of value, not that two objects are the same.

```
int firstInt = 5;
int secondInt = 5;

if(firstInt == secondInt)
{
    System.out.println("Both point to same object");
    // NO - neither point to an object -- their alues are the same.
}
```

You can share the same Integer object among multiple references by explicitly using `Integer.valueOf(int)`, which may return the same object for multiple calls.

Comment: Exactly where are these multiple references stored? and how is it ensured they will all point to same int variable( which is on the heap considering it is an instance variable)?

Comment: In the case of the primitive local variables, the values are stored directly in the generated bytecode for the method, and the local variables are stored on the stack. There are no references to either. In the case of Integer.valueOf(), the shared objects are stored by the Integer class in a private cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
if (Integer.valueOf(2) ==Integer.valueOf(2))
```

you will get `true`.

With the `Integer firstInt = new Integer(2)` you create a new local variable that is `!=` to another local variable created with `Integer secondInt = new Integer(2)`. Same goes for `String` type.

The reason behind this is that `==` checks equality of the variables. Variables could be different (`==` results in `false`) even though they point to two objects that are "the same". The same in this context means `obj1.equals(obj2)` returns `true`.

If you want object representation of primitve types and also StringS to be stored in **PermGen** then do not use `new` keyword, i.e. `Integer firstInt = 2;`, `String firstString= "whatevs";` beacause the keyword `new` creates an object on the **heap**.

Comment: If not overridden obj1.equals(obj2) internally calls == operator only. My question is as in 1st case of question how does JVM take care to ensure both int variables have same memory allocates?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, to answer advanced questions it is enough to look through source code. For instance, here is the code of `Integer#valueOf(int i)` method:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Values `IntegerCache#low` and `IntegerCache#high` could be changed via vm options:

> The size of the cache may be controlled by the `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>` option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a very valid question that needs to be answered. For any future readers, the way the == operation works for Object types and primitive types are different.

Primitive types(int, char, double, long....) are evaluated by their values.
Whereas Primitive Wrappers (Integer, Double, String ....) are actually objects and not just values.

So when we use Integer class as

> Integer number = new Integer(10)

A new Object is created in the memory which is not the case for primitive data types.

The == evaluation checks the memory, as well as the value for the Object types and for primitive types, checks the value only.